# How to count the amount of rows being summed inside an SQL SUM function?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's a certain part of my SQL query:

```
SELECT pir.paymentInstrumentItemID AS id,
       SUM(pir.priceChange) AS priceSum,
       pir.clientInfoID AS clientID,
       IFNULL(SUM(pir.costChange), 0) AS selfPrice,
       pir.paymentInstrumentItemID
FROM paymentInstrumentRegister as pir

GROUP BY pir.paymentInstrumentItemID
```

What I need to do is to count the amount of rows that got grouped by inside the first SUM function and make a CASE statement out of it, so something like that:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN amtRows = 1 THEN 0 ELSE pir.priceChange) as priceSum
```

So basically whenever there is a single row I don't need the value, but as long as there's two or more of those, I need their sum.

Will appreciate feedback.

Comment: count(pir.priceChange) ?

Comment: can't you just add `COUNT(...) as qty,` and do programming langauge rest?

Comment: COUNT the GROUP BY parameters.

Comment: You can use HAVING to exclude the row as a whole

Comment: I'm still not very good at SQL, basically i need to use COUNT(pir.paymentInstrumentItemID) to get the number of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option is to add `COUNT()` to query, and let programming language to do the rest, but if you really need do that by MySQL:

```
SELECT
    id,
    (CASE WHEN amtRows = 1 THEN 0 ELSE priceSum) as priceSum,
    amtRows,
    clientID,
    selfPrice,
    paymentInstrumentItemID
FROM (

    SELECT
        pir.paymentInstrumentItemID AS id,
        SUM(pir.priceChange) AS priceSum,
        COUNT(pir.priceChange) as as amtRows,
        pir.clientInfoID AS clientID,
        IFNULL(SUM(pir.costChange),0) AS selfPrice,
        pir.paymentInstrumentItemID
    FROM 
        paymentInstrumentRegister as pir
    GROUP BY 
        pir.paymentInstrumentItemID 

) tmp
```

Comment: Is there a way I could make the inner query to be outer instead, i.e. inside the SUM function? I would kinda prefer to not ruin the integrity of how it was set up.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask if it is possible to count the rows just inside the SUM function instead?

Comment: @nainy no. another solution is less efficient `LEFT JOIN` subquery. Can't you just do it in programming language you use??

Comment: Guessing i'd have to resort to doing that in PHP via selectors, because too much stuff should be changed in my code in order to do that in SQL how you set it up. I usually try to avoid doing that in higher layers of logic though, hence the question. Thanks for your answer anyway :)